# WPF ListView ItemTemplate Cannot set properties on property elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, itemtemplate

I am working on ListView in WPF, I want the `ListView` to get `ItemLists` from a `ViewModel` but I am getting the following error
**Cannot set properties on property elements**

xaml code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Name="mainSideMenuList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="#FF284593" Foreground="#FF3457D1">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction
            Command="{Binding Command}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mainSideMenuList, Path=SelectedItem}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate Height="60">
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding IconKind}" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 10" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
private readonly ItemHandler _itemHandler;
private ICommand _command;
public MainWindowViewModel() {
 _itemHandler = new ItemHandler();
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Settings", PackIconKind.Settings));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Products", PackIconKind.FoodForkDrink));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Tickets", PackIconKind.Ticket));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Entities", PackIconKind.Table));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Accounts", PackIconKind.Calculator));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Inventory", PackIconKind.Database));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Printing", PackIconKind.Printer));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Reports", PackIconKind.FileAccount));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Automation", PackIconKind.Calculator));
 _itemHandler.Add(new Item("Users", PackIconKind.User));
}
public List < Item > MenuItems {
 get {
  return _itemHandler.MenuItems;
 }
}
public ICommand Command {
 get {
  return _command ? ? (_command = new RelayCommand(x => {
   DoStuff(x as Item);
  }));
 }
}

private void DoStuff(Item item) {
 MessageBox.Show(item.Name + " element clicked");
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve?

Comment: Your ViewModel needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to let the Bindind works.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: My model implements ```INotifyPropertyChanged```.


List Items are displayed in the designer, but when it's time to run, I get the error

Comment: `ListView.ItemTemplate` is a _property_ and not a _type_. Properties don't have attributes, but types do. A property stores the reference to an instances of its type. In XAML's [Property Element Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail#property-element-syntax) `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` is a property element. Knowing this, you should now be able to understand the error message: _"Cannot set properties on property elements"_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that the `ListView.ItemTemplate` is of type `DataTemplate` which is not a `FrameworkElement` so it can not have any `Height` or `Width`or anything else which has to do with `UI-Elements`. It can only have one `Content` and this is a `DataTemplate` which can hold one `FrameworkElement`, mostly a `Panel`. These element then can have a `height` or `width` or any `UI-Element` property.

Therefore remove the `Height` of `<ListView.ItemTemplate Height="60">` and set it to the `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">`

Comment: Almost. The correct explanation is, that ListView.ItemTemplate is a _property_ and not a _type_. Properties don't have attributes, but types do. A property stores the reference to an instances of its type.

Comment: Thanks @dstreissi. I actually figured that out when I was doing try and error earlier. I have already removed the ```Height``` property